# shiny R app won't display text

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I'm trying to get Shiny (R) to display the lowest temperature (random data for testing) in a second row defined by a second fluidRow statement, but with no luck.  This isn't for a production script.  I'm just trying to learn Shiny.  I have a feeling I'm not calling things properly between the ui and server components, but I don't know what.  Any help would be appreciated.

Also, I'm wondering if anyone has any thoughts on me using a Shiny application for weather data with potentially millions of rows.  Will this be slow, or even impossible?  Thank you.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 100*1024^2)

# Define UI for data upload app ----
ui <- fluidPage(

# App title ----
titlePanel("My First Shiny App"),

fluidRow(
column(width = 3,
       # Input: Select a file ----
       fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                 multiple = FALSE,
                 accept = c("text/csv",".csv"))
)
),

fluidRow(
  column(width = 3,
       textOutput("info")
)
)
)

# Define server logic to read selected file ----
server <- function(input, output) {

output$contents <- renderText({

req(input$file1)

df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath, header = TRUE)

output$info <- renderText({
  return(min(df$Temp))     
 })

})
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)

Date,Temp,Precipitation,Station
2018-01-01 00:05:00,-1,0,ATRS2
2018-01-02 00:10:00,-10,0,BSNS2
2018-01-03 00:15:00,-2,0,BKMS2
2018-01-04 00:20:00,-1,0,ATRS2
2018-01-05 00:25:00,-9,0,BSNS2
2018-01-06 00:30:00,-10,0,BKMS2
2018-01-07 00:35:00,-6,0,ATRS2
2018-01-08 00:40:00,-10,0,BSNS2
2018-01-09 00:45:00,-5,0,BKMS2
2018-01-10 00:50:00,-2,0,ATRS2
2018-01-11 00:55:00,-6,0.254,BSNS2
2018-01-12 01:00:00,-1,0.254,BKMS2
2018-01-13 01:05:00,-7,0,ATRS2
2018-01-14 01:10:00,-3,0,BSNS2
2018-01-15 01:15:00,-10,0,BKMS2
2018-01-16 01:20:00,-10,0,ATRS2
2018-01-17 01:25:00,-2,0,BSNS2
2018-01-18 01:30:00,-8,0,BKMS2
2018-01-19 01:35:00,-9,0,ATRS2
2018-01-20 01:40:00,-4,0,BSNS2
2018-01-21 01:45:00,-8,0,BKMS2
2018-01-22 01:50:00,-3,0,ATRS2
2018-01-23 01:55:00,-2,0,BSNS2
2018-01-24 02:00:00,-3,0,BKMS2
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not seeing any output is because `output$info` is nested inside `output$contents`, and `output$contents` is never called because you don't have a matching `textOutput("contents")`.

My suggestion is to move all data loading outside of reactive functions, as discussed in the Execution section of [Tutorial Lesson 5](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson5/). You should then also unnest `output$info` and put it on the same level as other `output$...` functions.

Comment: Thank you, but how am I supposed to move data loading outside of reactive functions when the user needs to choose the file location?

Comment: Ah. If the user is choosing the file, then you'll probably want to isolate data loading into a separate `reactive` function that your `render*` functions can call. This will ensure that you are not reloading the data every time your UI needs updating, but only when the actual input changes. There are some examples in Lesson 6: https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson6/

Answer (score 0):

Replace the server with the following:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$info <- renderText({
  req(input$file1)
  df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath, header = TRUE)
  min(df$Temp)   
 })

}
```